# How will Qt 5.0 be packaged for Raring?

Tags: qt, policy, qt5

> <sup>**Note:** as per [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), "Issues with the next version of Ubuntu" may not be asked as questions here but in my opinion, this is not an issue but merely a question asking about *policy*. If you feel this question is off-topic, please leave a comment explaining why or open a question on [Meta.AU](http://meta.askubuntu.com).</sup>

How will Qt 5.0 be packaged for Ubuntu when it is released? Currently, the name of the package for installing the Qt 4.8 core libraries is:

[libqt4-core [image: Install libqt4-core]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqt4-core)

Will the equivalent package for the next version of Qt (5.0) be named `libqt5-core`? If not, what will the package be named? Will the existing Qt 4.8 libraries coexist with the Qt 5.0 equivalents for the foreseeable future or will they be removed?

[The Qt 5.0 beta 2 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-beta2) contains a lot of packages - few of which seem to correspond with existing package names.

If someone can provide me with a link to a policy outlining the Qt 5.0 migration plan, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Library package names in Ubuntu include the major abi version. Some examples are `libc6`, `libkrb5` and `libqt4`. So the Qt 5.0 libraries will be `libqt5-*`. Naming them `libqt4-*` would be *wrong* as they are not backwards compatible and packages depending on Qt 4.x would suddenly stop working if Ubuntu would do this. Naming the packages `libqt5-*` (and taking care of possible filename clashes) allows them to be installed simultaneously so you can run Qt 4.x and Qt 5.x apps on the same machine.